# Force Save As, MS Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a bit of a newby with VBA in MS Office products. I've been searching for some code that will force a user to "Save As' a .xls file I use as a template (but it's not an actual template file type)

Basically, I have this:

1. User opens .xls, enters some data into some field and then File-->Save As to their own location
2. Sometimes user clicks save instead, therefore overwriting the .xls which I don't want to happen.

I've been looking into some ideas, but I'm not sure how to implement it the best. I think a prompt when the user first opens the .xls to save to a new location is the best approach, but thinking forward, if they have already saved the file to a new location and decide to edit the new one, I want them to be able to 'Save' at that point because now it is their own file, not the original.

If someone can point me in the right direction or find flaws in my logic, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Put the file in a shared folder and flag as readonly, or give read-only access to the folder? Make the file available as a web download ? Depends on your exact sitation.

Comment: This is exactly what templates are for. You open the template and it creates a copy of the file which you must save as a new workbook. You would have to deliberately save the new file as a template in order to duplicate what you describe.

Answer (score 6):

> I use as a template (but it's not an actual template file type)

The most simplest way is to save the file with `Read-Only Recommended` set to true. See the snapshot

[image]

That ways even if the user tries to do a `Save`, Excel will automatically prompt for a `Save As`

[image]

HTH

Comment: If I setup excel this way and the user opens and 'Save As', will the new saved spreadsheet allow you to 'Save' at that point? it would be good if it did.

Comment: @Mike: You can only do a "Save As" in the above scenario :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the others that templates and read-only are better options, but if you're set on rolling your own, here's an example to get you started.  It goes in the ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim sNewName As String

    Cancel = True 'Cancel the save operation

    sNewName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Replace(Me.Name, ".xls", "1.xls"))

    If sNewName <> Me.FullName And sNewName <> "False" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.SaveAs sNewName
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 This IS another good solution, but just remember if the user disables macros then this will not work.