# Force Save as XLSM when user clicks close button

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to enforce the user save in xlsm. The problem is this code works properly in save as event, but it doesn't work when the user clicks the close button. When the close button is hit, Excel shows a dialog box offering save options with all kinds of filetypes. How can I get the same behavior of the code below considering user clicked the close button? 
Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim txtFileName As String

'1. Check of Save As was used.
  If SaveAsUI = True Then
    Cancel = True

'2. Call up your own dialog box.  Cancel out if user Cancels in the dialog box.
   txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
    If txtFileName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled.", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

'3. Save the file.
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. Also perhaps [`Saved`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196613.aspx) property may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555456/force-save-as-ms-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this code in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event to cover that issue. I just tested it and it worked.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

If ThisWorkbook.FileFormat <> 52 Then '52 is enum for xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")

    If txtFileName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled.", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an FYI - and I doubt this is the case here but may be for others reaching this page - the `xlFileFormat` enum is slightly different on Mac OS, and some of the numbers are not the same so in that case it's better to use the xl constant `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` which is also pointed out in the code above as a comment. [More info here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm)

Answer (score 0):

@Scott-Holtzman, your idea saved me. I have to made some changes considering my specific problems. When the fileformat is already xlsm, excel shows an inbuilt standard message box offering saving options. At this point, the user can choose others fileformats. So I've omitted the difference clause and have included a msgbox to allow user complete the exit process. Thank you very much for your help!! This is my final version:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim msg As String
Dim ireply As Integer

If Not Me.Saved Then
    msg = "Do you want to Save this book? "
    ireply = MsgBox(msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
    Select Case ireply
        Case vbNo
            Me.Saved = True
            Exit Sub
        Case vbCancel
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End If

txtFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")

If txtFileName = "False" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled.", vbOKOnly
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=txtFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```